# How to ignore .catch promise in code coverage with istanbul?

Tags: javascript, promise, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm using BluebirdJS promise library and I have `.catch` that I can't mock that is why I can't cover it with my code coverage using istanbul.

```
.then(() => ....)
/* istanbul ignore next */ -> Does not work
.catch((err) => err) /// I want to ignore this
```

Is this possible with istanbul library?

This is the full code, my test can't reach the `.catch` because it's always passing and I can't seem to another way to force mongoose to throw an error

```
 const { payload } = request

 const group = new LocationGroups(payload)

 group.save()
   .then(reply)
   .catch((error) => reply(boomify(error)))
```

Comment: Try making it testable? Why do you think you can't mock it?

Comment: How about putting the comment inside the callback that should be ignored?

Comment: @Bergi Please see my edit. I'm not sure how to force mongoose to force an error with `.save`

Comment: @Bergi putting the comment inside won't work because I can't reach it. Thanks btw, for the comment :)

Comment: You can't force mongoose to do anything, but you could just mock `save`?What libraries do you use for testing?

Answer (score 4):

```
try {

} catch (err) /* istanbul ignore next */ {

}
```

Comment: this doesn't even answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
group.save()
   .then(reply)
   .catch(  /* istanbul ignore next */(error) => reply(boomify(error)))
```

Alternatively, you can wrap your catch in another block

```
 try {
    stuff()
  } catch (err) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */ {
      console.error(err)
      throw err
    }
  }
```